# How to evaluate $\int \sqrt{1-n\cos(\omega t)}\,dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How can I evaluate $$\int \sqrt{1-n\cos(\omega t)}\,dt$$

I don't even know if this is even elementary. Just found it on an astronomy problem. If necessary, evaluate from $0$ to $2\pi/\omega$.

Comment: I was wondering is there are bounds on the $n$. For n = 1, the answer is trivial via the half angle formula for sin, for values of $n>1$, the integral is undefined. Also please add some strategies you tried yourself.

Comment: ah, of course! $n  \in R $, $n \geq 0$. I'm not an expert in this of doing integrals, i tried the basic techniques of u sub and ibp. After that, i tried to work with the sub-integrals i obtained doing that but they didn't seem as they were easier.

Comment: definitely [not](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%5Csqrt%7B1-n%5Ccos%28wt%29%7Ddt) elementary.

Comment: $-1\lt{n}\lt{1}$ otherwise you can’t integrate from $0$ to $\frac{2\pi}{w}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer involves incomplete elliptic integral of second kind, which can be seen here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind

You can rewrite the integral as

$$\int\sqrt{1-n}\sqrt{\frac{2n\sin^2(\frac{\omega t}{2})}{1-n}+1} \, dt$$ and substitute $u=\frac{\omega t}{2}$. After some calculation, you can see how the elliptic integral works.

Comment: oh, thanks! i think i must have a lot to learn then haha

Comment: If substitution is more comfortable, search up Weierstrass substitution, unfortunately I haven't had the time to work out a solution myself, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Almost as @Mike answered, consider $$I=\int \sqrt{1-n\cos(\omega t)}\,dt$$ Let $\omega t=2x$
$$I=\frac{2 }{\omega }\int\sqrt{1-n \cos (2 x)}\,dx=\frac{2 }{\omega }\int \sqrt{(1-n)+2 n \sin ^2(x)}\,dx$$
$$I=\frac{2 \sqrt{1-n}}{\omega }\int\sqrt{1-\frac {2n}{n-1}\sin ^2(x)}\,dx=\frac{2 \sqrt{1-n}}{\omega } E\left(x\left|\frac{2 n}{n-1}\right.\right)$$ Back to $t$
$$I=\frac{2 \sqrt{1-n}}{\omega } E\left(\frac{ \omega t}{2}|\frac{2 n}{n-1}\right)$$ This makes
$$J=\int_0^{\frac {2\pi} \omega} \sqrt{1-n\cos(\omega t)}\,dt=\frac{4 \sqrt{1-n} }{\omega }E\left(\frac{2 n}{n-1}\right)$$

If, for practical purposes, you need a quite decent approximation (except very close to $n=1$) you could use
$$J=\frac {2 \pi} \omega\left(1- \sum_{k=1}^p a_k\, t^k \right)\qquad \text{where}\qquad t=\frac {n^2}{16}$$ The sequence of the $a_k$'s is
$$\left\{1,\frac{15}{4},\frac{105}{4},\frac{15015}{64},\frac{153153}{64},\frac{6789
   783}{256},\frac{79676025}{256},\frac{62386327575}{16384},\frac{787916211225}{1
   6384},\cdots\right\}$$

Comment: wow, thanks! Just i have a doubt: When you integrate $$\int \sqrt{1- \frac{2n}{n-1}sin^2(x)}dx$$ You say that it should be =$E(x \vert \frac{2n}{n-1}$ ) but it shouldn't be $= E(x \vert \sqrt{\frac{2n}{n-1}})$ ?
Really, i'm really nooby. Sorry if this sounds trivial.

Comment: @ArturoRuiz. This is Mathemetica notation (which differs from the usual one by a square as you notice